# read ViewText convert to double

Tags: android, string, double

My app has a number of numeric user input fields which need sanity checks before proceeding to the next intent.
I read viewText fields, convert them to double and then do the (numeric) tests but odd things happen and I find that while the code runs on my HTC in debug, it falls over if I publish then download the published version. My code is sumarised as;

```
    String sFy;
    double  mFy=0;D
    sFy=(txtFy.getText().toString());
    mFy=Double.parseDouble(sFy);
```

if sFy is null the .parsedouble crashes. If I use;

```
    sFy=(txtFy.getText().toString());
    mFy=getDouble(sFy); 

    private double getDouble(String string){
    double temp=0.0;
    try {
        temp = Double.parseDouble(string.trim());
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
       System.out.println("getDouble, Could not parse " + nfe);
    }         
    return temp;        
}
```

it works, even if sFy is empty.

Can anyone tell my why, or suggest a 'correct' method?

Comment: Do yo mean to say your getDouble workd even if sFy is null??

Comment: Yes, even if the ViewText box is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like that :

```
String sFy;
double  mFy=0;
sFy = txtFy.getText();
if ((sFy != ""){
    mFy=Double.parseDouble(sFy);  
}
```

Or maybe I haven't really understood your problem...

Comment: I am new to Android/Java and was looking for confirmation of method, and maybe thoughts on why an app would run on a phone in debug but not, on the same phone, when installed from the market. 1 out of two is not too bad I guess.

Comment: Check if there is no conflicts with the SDK version using for debug test and the android version of the phone..

Answer (score 0):

Your getDouble is returning 0.0 in case there is NumberFormatException.
Do you see debugger coming to System.out.println("getDouble, Could not parse " + nfe);